# Align vertices in straight line in the uv image editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I am in the UV Image editor.  I am trying to align each row of vertices in the x axis.  When all the rows are aligned, I would like to align each row on the Y axis. Is there a combination of key strokes I can use in the image editor to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can select all vertices in a row by using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on an edge;

[image]

You can align selected vertices on the x axis with the following keystrokes (one after the other, not all at once);

<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

Same for the Y axis, select with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>

[image]

<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

(those are zeros, not the letter o)

Continuing this process, you can align the desired vertices on x...;

[image]

Then y...;

[image]